# Why is my device with "normal" screen dividied by Android studio as "small" screen device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have that problem:

i have  two layout folders `layout-small` and `layout`

When i change rendering device on preview when editing `layout` to Nexus S (It have "normal" screen) Android studio will open the `layout-small` and let me edit small screen layout which is displayed on Nexus S.

Same issues with other "normal" screen devices

thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android documentation: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[image]

As you can see in this image, a device's actual size is not certain to belong to either small or normal. Some sizes belong to both categories. Also please note that on android's manifest setting targetSdk may affect the judgement.

Comment: so 3.4 inches screen can be normal and small screen size and is in this case defined screen size by manufactuer in rom?

Comment: @PcAF I'm not sure who defines the size of the screen, it must be the manufacturer, but I can't tell for sure. As a programmer you should keep in mind that you should support either case, there could be screens of 3.4 inches that use normal screen size assets and others that use small screen size assets and there is nothing wrong with it (as in it's not in your -the programmer's- control and you shouldn't mind it).

Comment: so why has Nexus 6 (size 5.96 inches) "normal"

Comment: @PcAF I already told you sizes are not certain, the numbers you see in the image are not specific, but there are other reasons that would explain taking wrong layouts like giving different names in layouts for different screen sizes, or setting an old `targetSdk`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Try to rename your "layout" in "layout-normal". In this way Android Studio recognizes the right layout type for "normal-sized" devices and assigns the "layout-small" just to Android Wear devices.
My advice to set a well formatted "layout-normal" is to design it on the smallest device available for "layout-normal" (Nexus One 3,7").